# Can I migrate from ClearCase to Serena VM?

Tags: migration, clearcase, pvcs, serena

I have a repository using **Rational ClearCase Explorer 2003.06.10+** which I want to migrate into **Serena ChangeMan Version Manager 8.1.4.2**.

Is this possible?  The **ClearCase** repository was not used for all it's functions, just as a place to hold copies of documents, so the only thing I need to keep is the files and their version histories.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would recommend would be through a ClearCase dynamic view:

- listing all labels one at a time,
- for each label, check in which branch the files are visualized, and take the branch used the most aside /main (so for 400 files, if 3 of them in a branch 'patch', consider as an export -- source -- branch the 'patch' one)
- create /reuse the corresponding branch to the export branch in Serena, so here a branch 'patch'
- import (create items) in Serena from that dynamic view, and remember that directories are not versionned the way they are in ClearCase. So you will loose directory history, but will retain the main history for the files, that is the versions having received a label.

The key is to go from the oldest label to the newest, recreate the branch as you go and only import labelized versions.

Does that help ?