# ClearCase to Serena DM CM Migration

Tags: migration, database-migration, clearcase, serena

Is there a way to migrate from ClearCase 7 to Dimensions 12.2.2.6?

Also, is this possible while retaining all the history and Baseline information? I am currently researching the possibility of migration.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to migrate form ClearCase 7 to Dimensions 12.2.2.6.

Not really, not with its *full* history.

As you saw, [back in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201918/6309), I recommended picking a few labels and branches, and import one by one a coherent set of files (one set per label)

That remains a manual process though, and won't take into account ClearCase-specific metadata like merge Hyperlinks and UCM elements.

Comment: Thank you Von I was hoping things had changed by now :(